# How to remove any non-steam game from the library

Tags: steam

I had the brilliant idea of adding Excel and PowerPoint to my library as non-steam games (yup...). At some point, I wanted to remove them. However, surprise, surprise, the "Right Click / Manage / Remove non-Steam game from your library" option was gone. In fact, the only option I got from Right Click was "Launch", "Add to Category" and "Properties".

So I spent a couple of minutes looking around and the best solution I was able to find was a way to remove all non-steam games from the library. This didn't work for me, since I only wanted to remove those two and keep the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Non-Steam Shortcuts are saved to the file `.../steam/userdata/{user ID #}/config/shortcuts.vdf`. It is a binary VDF (Valve Data Format), and so is hard to modify without [using code](https://github.com/CorporalQuesadilla/Steam-Shortcut-Manager/wiki) to read/write the file, or a hex editor if you're okay with that. There's some [unofficial documentation](https://github.com/CorporalQuesadilla/Steam-Shortcut-Manager/wiki/Steam-Shortcuts-Documentation) which could simplify using a hex editor though.

Comment: Will take a look once I get home. Looks promising.

Comment: It should work as Valve does not change important core parts of the Steam client often because there's so much legacy code to worry about breaking. Lol.